# How to get lastest N records of each group in mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a couple of entries for each cities. How to get lastest 3 entries of each city? Like:

City1
record 1
record 2
record 3

City2
record 1
record 2
record 3

City3
record 1
record 2
record 3

The schema:

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
  city: {type: String},
  title: {type: String},
  created: {type: Number, default: Math.floor(new Date() / 1000)}
})
```

The code I've tried:

```
Collection
.find('location $in ' + cities)
.aggregate({$group: {location: "$location"}})
.sort('created: 1')
.limit(3).exec(function(err, docs) { res.render('index', { hash: docs }); });
```

So, how to perform a query where I should have as result: 3 most recent titles of each city

Comment: It's tagged, but just to be clear: you're using mongoose, right?

Comment: also, are you wanting to return one group or multiple groups? Another clarification: are each of these cities their own collection, individual objects, or what?

Comment: yes, right! I'm using mongoose.

Comment: All the same collection. Collection XYZ and all of these records are fields of it.

Comment: cool; might be worth formatting a little differently. I'll add an edit. :)

Comment: can you post the schema or at least the relevant parts of it?

Comment: I'm waiting to return a group of records. Each group are represented for a city. For each city the last N records. This collection XYZ contains a timestamp field.

Comment: so are you running an aggregation? More info about what you're currently doing and have tried === better answers :)

Comment: Yes. It seems I might run a aggregation to perform this query. I'm new in mongo and also searching for something to solve it. Actually my question should be: "Is it possible to perform this query"?

Comment: Thanks so much for posting the relevant code!

Comment: I'm looking for how to perform a query where I should have as result:
3 most recent titles of each city

Comment: what are you currently getting from the query?

Comment: I'm getting error because I'm not so familiar with query aggregation in mongodb at all. btw I'm looking for fixing the query and post here a little bit more information

Comment: gotcha! let's see how we can fix this now :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In **mongoDB 3.2** you can perform this by using the aggregate query of following form:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
  {$sort: {created: -1}},
  {$group: {_id:'$city', title:{$push: '$title'}},
  {$project: {_id:0, city: '$_id', mostRecentTitle: {$slice: ['$title', 0, 2]}}}
)
```

Its very difficult to achieve the same using mongoDB 3.0. A very dirty trick is there to achieve this in 3.0. It involves a couple of steps and other collection.

First do an aggregate and output the result to a temporary collection called 'aggr_out'

**Query:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {created: -1}},
  {$group: {_id:'$city', title:{$push: '$title'}},
  {$project: {city: '$_id', mostRecentTitle: '$title'}},
  {$out: 'aggr_out'}]
)
```

Using above query, mostRecentTitle will have all the recent titles ordered from index 0, 1, 2, ... If you are happy with this result using this as you already have the result in indexes 0,1 and 2 of mostRecentTitle. Other titles can be simple ignored in application side.

Still if you are not happy, do an update on the output collection 'aggr_out', and read data from this collection. The query is,

```
db.aggr_out.update(
  {},
  {$push: {
    mostRecentTitle: {$each:[], $slice:3}
    }
  }
)
```

The above operation will slice the mostRecentTitle array so that it has most recent three titles. Do a read on this collection to get your desired result.

Comment: I got this error "unrecognized pipeline stage name $project"

Comment: { [MongoError: exception: invalid operator '$slice'] ..}

Comment: How you mentioned, there's no slice for mongodb 3.0.x version that's mine. maybe I can find a other way over slice.

Comment: Is there an alternative for $slice?

Comment: No its not a map-reduce. Its a helper to save the result of aggregation to a new collection. It also helps in cases you don't have enough memory in system to complete aggregation. see https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/aggregation/out/

Comment: I checked the database and could see a new collection called "aggr_out" as result of $out aggregation. Thanks buddy!

Comment: I performed this query oggr.update({}, {$push: {title: {$each:[], $slice:3}}}, function(err,raw) {  console.log(err);console.log(raw); }) 
Do you see anything wrong? it is moongose query!

Comment: this is what I get from result { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }

Comment: Has a bug to update multiple arrays in a single operation. I modified a little your solution
      col.find({},'_id',function(err,docs){
        docs.forEach(function(doc) {
          col.update({ _id: doc['_id'] },{$push: {'title': {$each:[], $slice:5}}}
        })
      })