# update in mongodb with $in query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have three arrays coupon_ids, id_counter and increase_ctr. Now the value of coupon_id at any index is present at same index in id_counter and in increase_ctr. So for coupon_id "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25f0" id_counter value is 200 and increase_ctr is 5.

```
coupon_ids = ["584559bd1f65d363bd5d25f0", "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25f1", "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25f2", "584559bd1f65d363bd5d25f4"];

id_counter = [200, 300, 400];

increase_ctr = [5, 6, 7];

couponmodel.findAndUpdate({'_id' : { $in : coupons_ids }, "id_counter": id_counter[index] /* how to get id_counter corresponding to index which is matched inside $in */}, { id_counter: new_id_counter, $inc: {curr_ctr: increase_ctr /* how to get increate_ctr corresponding to index which is matched inside $in */} }, function(err, numberAffected, raw){
    if(err){

    } else {

    }
});
```

Now can anyone please tell me how can i write above query so that for coupon_id[index] i can use "id_counter" = id_counter[index] and "increase_ctr" = increase_ctr[index] in the query.

If we could use $update with aggregate then my problem will get solved easily but as Aggregates does not support $update how can i solve my problem.

Comment: Update 1 coupon at a time.

Comment: yes but it will increase time on my server that's why thinking about any other solution ?? why can't be do that in a single query ??

Comment: I doubt so. All the [bulk update](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/Bulk.find.update/) is happening on the client side. There is no roundtrip overhead. Number of disk IO depends on number of documents to update, not on number of requests. Could you elaborate why you think time would increase?

Comment: i mean to run 10 queries parrallely don't you think it would be a lot better to update them in one single query ??

Comment: @AlexBlex can you please look at below question, i am having problem with Bulk Update as suggested by you. Please reply.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163644/unordered-bulk-updates-how-to-know-which-updates-were-successfull-and-which-were

Comment: @AlexBlex are you there buddy ??

Comment: Dear Prakash, I understand your impatience, but it's a no-commitment forum of voluntary members. Whilst waiting for a help from community, you could make good use of time by reading the docs http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/BulkWriteResult.html. Have you tried to use `getWriteErrors()` at all? Remember, the questions that do not show any research efforts are being ignored at best. Sometimes downvoted.

Comment: i am very sorry but in my get write errors i got nothing my output from bulk is this {"ok":1,"writeErrors":[],"writeConcernErrors":[],"insertedIds":[],"nInserted":0,
"nUpserted":0,"nMatched":1,"nModified":1,"nRemoved":0,"upserted":[],"lastOp":{"ts":"6364374546002214913","t":1}}

Comment: that's why i asked you ??

Comment: but in query i am sending three bul updates ?? but only one matched and modified and for rest 2 there is no description.

Comment: Then they don't match. No errors, 1 query matched and modified. What's the problem?

Comment: i want to get index of unmatched update queries so that i can update them again. pls help

Comment: whoa whoa whoa! don't you think it is slightly out of scope of the question? Now we have something to do with documents that did not match. How did you expect it to be done within a single *"with $in query"* in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update multiple documents based on diffrent queries with diffrent updates, However updating the seperate documents should be pretty fast as you won't be waiting for the previous update to have happend on the document.